# My Spring Boot application isn't understanding bcrypt for some reason

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bcrypt

I'm using Spring Boot and I wanted to save a password in

```
src/main/resources/application.properties
```

with this line:

```
spring.datasource.password={bcrypt}$2y$18$nBz3NZD6ygFL/MvgLm9lu.rZvfCjNhQRqpHBw4VkBphOzxxMUi1nW
```

On my business pc it worked but now it tells me it can't connect to user postgres with the provided password. I'm not using BcryptEncoder or something like that. I didn't do that on the other project as well. Now that it accidentally got deleted I'm not sure anymore what I should do.

Comment: If this is an actively used password i would suggest changing the salted hash.

Comment: It is only needed while starting the application.

Comment: bcrypt is a one-way hash. You cannot use this as a datasource password (because you have to have that in plain text)

Comment: But how did it work on my other project? I had the same password twice. One for Spring Security and one for Spring Data JPA and it worked. (it was a sandbox connection, so it's okay to use the same password twice)

Comment: As I said it cannot work with bcrypt - maybe you were using something different like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt

Comment: Definitely not Jasypt.

Comment: The password in `spring.datasource.password` is used as plain text (unless you use something like Jasypt to wrap the `PropertySource`s to decrypt values). But by default it is used as is. If it worked on your work PC (which I doubt) you probably passed, somewhere, a different value for `spring.datasource.password` or the Postgres instance you connect to used that value as the password. Either way Spring Security's `PasswordEncoder` is never going to be used for the `spring.datasource.password` property.